# Adding cast as decimal in numerator and/or denominator?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How does the cast change the division results? Or am I supposed to cast both?

```
select 1/(cast(3 as decimal(6,2)))
select (cast(1 as decimal(6,2)))/3
select (cast(1 as decimal(6,2)))/(cast(3 as decimal(6,2)))

select 4/(cast(3 as decimal(6,2)))
select (cast(4 as decimal(6,2)))/3
select (cast(4 as decimal(6,2)))/(cast(3 as decimal(6,2)))
select 220020212/(cast(3 as decimal(6,2)))
```

Returns

```
0.3333333
0.333333
0.333333333
1.3333333
1.333333
1.333333333
73340070.6666666
```

Comment: The precision and scale of the results of arithmetic involving decimals is defined in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Just for fun, watch what happens with select  1/cast(3 as money)

Comment: Also see [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql). For more fun try `select 30 / 5 / 3 as Two, 30 / -5 / 3 as NotTwo;`. SQL Server uses an _unconventional_ [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), hence evaluating `( 30 / 5 ) / 3` (equals `6 / 3`) and `30 / -( 5 / 3 )` (equals `30 / -1` due to integer division).

Answer (score 0):

I Like to set my columns to numeric first, that way I don't have to convert them to decimals.

```
SELECT 
[COL1]/[COL2]
FROM(
SELECT [COL1] = CAST(1 AS NUMERIC), [COL2] = CAST(2 AS NUMERIC)) AS [SUB1]
```